# Why is the constant term in any chromatic polynomial is always zero?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

The chromatic polynomial $P(G,\lambda)$ is simply the number of different way in which we can colour a graph $G$ with at-most $\lambda$ different colours. Such that every pair of adjacent vertices gets different colours.

It's obvious that $P(K_n,\lambda) = \lambda^n$ using the rule of product.
It turns out that for any graph, this constant term in the polynomial is always zero. But why this is the case ?

If we have zero colours then of course there is zero number of different ways to colour a graph, but again this is not what the question is asking. Any ideas ?

Comment: But that is what the question is asking. That is the reason the constant term is 0.

Comment: A minor issue: You use the rule of product to conclude $P(K_n, \lambda) = \lambda^n$.

Comment: If there are no vertices, then there is **one** way to color the vertices with zero colors.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez In a graph we allow $E =\emptyset$ but $V \neq \emptyset$ is part of definition.

Comment: Well, that depends on your definition!

Answer (score 3):

The value of a polynomial at $0$ is always the constant term of the polynomial; since $P(G,0)=0$, the constant term of $P(G,\lambda)$ must be $0$.

If the polynomial is $c_0+c_1\lambda+c_2\lambda^2+\ldots+\lambda^n$, and you substitute $\lambda=0$, you get $c_0$, so $c_0$ must be $0$.

Comment: But I think what the question is saying that if we have $\lambda = 2$ colours then the constant term of $P(G, \lambda)$ is also zero, not just $P(G,0)$ ?

Comment: @alkabary: $P(G,\lambda)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$. When you substitute $2$ for $\lambda$, you’re simply evaluating that polynomial at $\lambda=2$; you’re not getting a different polynomial. It just happens that when you evaluate any polynomial at $0$, you get the constant term of that polynomial. In this case the polynomial is the chromatic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out this is zero exactly because we cannot color the graph with $0$ colors.

If you don't like this proof, here is another proof:

You can do induction by the number of edges.

Your Induction Statement is the following:

If $G$ is a graph with $|E|=n$ then $X$ divides $P_G(X)$.

P(0) is easy, and the inductive step follows immediately by deletion-contraction.